# How to use NEXT button more efficiently

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a video based application that uses a button `click` event to change HTML `<source>` for the next video and a few other things. Initially there are separate hidden "next video" buttons for each video.

For example, at the end of video1 when #nextVideo2 button is clicked, video2 HTML info is updated, #nextVideo2 button is hidden and #nextVideo3 button is shown. And this process continues for each video.

This works fine for my 3 or 4 video prototype but I need to make this more efficient and scalable for a much larger number of videos.

My goal is to have a single "NEXT" button  and load the next numerical 'video' function each time the "NEXT" button is clicked instead of show/hide different buttons.

I'm a bit confused what the most appropriate method is to achieve this. Should I somehow call the video functions from an array or increment the video function number or something completely different?

```
<div id="videoApp">
    <video id="videoElement"><source src="video1.mp4"></video>

  <div id="startPage">
      <h3 id="startInfo">some video1 text</h3>
  </div>

  <div id="endPage">
      <div><button id="nextVideo2">Next Video</button></div>
   // the following buttons are initially hidden with CSS
      <div><button id="nextVideo3">Next Video</button></div>
      <div><button id="nextVideo4">Next Video</button></div>
      <div><button id="endApp">Finish</button></div>
    </div>
  </div>
```

Javascript

```
function video2() {
  $('#videoElement').html('<source src="video2.mp4">');
  $('#startInfo').html('some video2 text');
  $('#nextVideo2').hide(); $('#nextVideo3').show();
}

function video3() {
  $('#videoElement').html('<source src="video3.mp4">');
  $('#startInfo').html('some video3 text');
  $('#nextVideo3').hide(); $('#nextVideo4').show();
}

function video4() {
  $('#videoElement').html('<source src="video4.mp4">');
  $('#startInfo').html('some video4 text');
  $('#nextVideo4').hide(); $('#endApp').show();
}

$('#nextVideo2').click(video2);

$('#nextVideo3').click(video3);

$('#nextVideo4').click(video4);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could store the video src urls and other info in an array of objects. Either keep a reference to the current video or just look it up in the array when the next button is pressed. This example stores the url and textcomponent data in an array of objects.

```
videos = [ 
    { src: 'a.mp4', info: 'some text' }, 
    { src: 'b.mp4', info: 'some other text' }
];
currentVideoIndex = 0;

$('#nextVideo').click( function() {
    currentVideoIndex++;
    $('#videoElement').html('<source src="' + videos[currentVideoIndex].src + '">');
    $('#startInfo').html( videos[currentVideoIndex].info );

    if ( currentVideoIndex >= videos.length - 1 ) {
        $( this ).hide();
        $( '#endButton' ).show();
    }
});
```

Comment: I like this as it seems like a simple enough solution replacing only the video src info. How would you suggest modifying the text component by combining it with this? Having a separate array for video text component might get messy in the future if either is not updated correctly so combining it with this video array would be superb. Also what method would you use if I don't want to wrap to 0? Instead I want an "end" button after the last video that links elsewhere

Comment: I have updated the snippet to show how to combine the text and video src in a single array. I also switched it from an infinite next button that loops back to 0 to a next button that gets hidden at the last video and shows another end button element.

Comment: I'm using now this with 3 videos in the array. After video1, the "next video" button loads video2 info correctly. After video2, clicking on next video doesn't load video3. Instead video2 info remains. Curiously though after video2 plays a second time, the "end" button shows as if the last video (video3) has played. Not sure if I'm missing something in this code that stops the 2nd increment.

Comment: Seems like the code that sets the src and info shouldn't be in an else block. Adjusting the code now...

Comment: Exxxcellent! That works perfectly JasonB. I assumed it was something simple like that but my tinkering didn't get there. This appears to be the most concise and effective way to achieve my goal.

Answer (score 1):

```
<div id="videoApp">
  <video id="videoElement"></video>

  <div id="startPage">
    <h3 id="startInfo">some video1 text</h3>
  </div>

  <div id="endPage">
    <div><button id="nextVideo">Next Video</button></div>      
    <div><button id="endApp">Finish</button></div>
  </div>  
</div>

const _videos = [
  {id:"1", src:"video1.mp4", startInfo:"some video1 text"},
  {id:"2", src:"video2.mp4", startInfo:"some video2 text"},
  {id:"3", src:"video3.mp4", startInfo:"some video3 text"}   
];

let _currentIndex = 0;

 function init() { // probably on page load

    if( _videos.length > 0 ) {

    document.getElementById("videoElement").src = _videos[_currentIndex].src
    $('#startInfo').html(_videos[_currentIndex].startInfo);

    $('#nextVideo').click( function() {            
        _currentIndex++;
        // Check if we reached last video
        let isThisLastVideo = (_videos.length == (_currentIndex+1));
        document.getElementById("videoElement").src = _videos[_currentIndex].src;
        $('#startInfo').html(_videos[_currentIndex].startInfo);
        $(this).toggle(!isThisLastVideo) 
        $('#endApp').toggle(isThisLastVideo); 
    });
 } 
}
```

Comment: In theory this is something along the lines of my requirements but I can't get it to work. The click event doesn't update the #videoElement html. Should I be referencing the "src" and "startInfo" tags used in the "_videos" array somewhere? I don't understand how ``.html`` references that specific part of the array

Comment: Yes, sorry for being sloppy. You should refer the property names as _videos[_currentIndex].src  and _videos[_currentIndex].startInfo.

Comment: Thanks for updating, I play around with that. Is there any particular reason why you changed from ``$('#videoElement').html(``  to the ``document.getElementById("videoElement").src`` version?

Comment: Just for brevity. It should not make any difference. But It's good to use plain js whenever we can.:)